# Connect G Suite to Microsoft Cloud App Security

Tags: azure, oauth

Noob here: Attempting to follow guidance from this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-app-security/connect-google-apps-to-microsoft-cloud-app-security?redirectedfrom=MSDN

On step 7, the "OAuth consent screen" section, the steps to not comport with the GSuite GCP Gui options presented to me. How should the "OAuth consent screen" be configured?